# AFNetworking 2.0 always accepts the responds with status codes 400, 500, Responseobject is always nil

Tags: ios, http-status-codes, afnetworking-2

I am writing a simple client server application and had to update AFNetworking to version 2.0. My problem is even though I return 403 from my server, operation manager always drops into success block.

This is what I return from my Django server:

```
return HttpResponseForbidden(content_type="application/json")
```

I extended OperationManager as like this:

```
User : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

this is how I init:

```
-(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
        [self setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];

        [self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];        
    }
    return self;
}
```

and my get request looks like:

```
[self GET:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Get request success.");
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Get request failed.");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"connectionError" object: error];

    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
}];
```

I realized that the responseData of AFURLConnectionOperation is always null since this function of AFURLConnectionOperation is never called:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Thank you. I am waiting for your help!!

Comment: Same here. Did you find the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Unfortunately I couldnt